# What method of IPC for Linux Kernel space are best?

Tags: linux, kernel, ipc

Need recommendation for full duplex data exchange for Linux applications.
One application work in the Kernel space and other work in the User space.
Need to do exchange of data  (256 bytes per transaction).
What method of IPC will best?

Comment: Insufficient requirements for choose **single** best method. My suggestion is to implement *character device* with `.read` and `.write` methods.

Comment: Main requirements is stability of works.
I read about communication via: PIPES, FIFO-FILES, SEMAPHORES, SOCKETS, but I don't know what is better.

Comment: You enumerate things useful for **user space - user space** communication. Communication **kernel space - user space** uses another mechanisms. See, e.g., [there](http://wiki.tldp.org/kernel_user_space_howto).